# Scroll through list items like in google mail/rss reader

Tags: android

In both applications you have a list of items (mails, news headers) that you scroll vertical. You select an entry in the list to get the details view. E.g. view mails for a topic or read the news description. In this View you have the possibility to swipe to the previous/next item. The layout stays always the same but the content changes.

How to I implement this by myself?

I have found  no option to let the ListView scroll horizontal and ViewFlipper is about different Layouts. It can't be that difficult to scroll the details of a list horizontal.

Comment: sounds like a listview that takes you to a "DetailFragment" with a ViewPager on it with its adapter fed by the same data loaded into the ListAdapter.

Comment: @FoamGuy I was scared away by the "v4" in the package as the reader app had it already in android 2.2 but with a closer look it seems like the solution. I will test it tomorrow. When you make your comment an answer I can accept it.